# Spring Integration and Reactive WebSockets

Tags: java, spring, websocket, spring-integration, spring-websocket

Spring integration offers non-reactive inbound/outbound WebSocket adapters which, simply put, associate session with id via internal container, you do some processing on message, and on outbound, it checks message headers for session id, and sends it via that session.

Now, with Spring offering reactive WebSocket support via org.springframework.web.reactive.socket.WebSocketSession and other classes there, I'm wondering of there is similar support in terms of channel adapters for reactive WebSocket stack.

If not, are there any common patterns/practices, how would one integrate reactive WS with spring-integration message flows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature hasn't been called yet, so we haven't thought on the matter.

Please, take a look into my [SandBox](https://github.com/artembilan/sandbox/tree/master/spring-integration-websocket-reactive). This is the best I can suggest with the current state of situation.

We just follow the standard Spring WebFlux suggestions to implement a WebSockets solution. So, we have there a `WebSocketHandler` implementation with an appropriate URL mapping. The implementation just forward a `Flux` from the `session.receive()` into the `IntegrationFlow` registered dynamically. The flow then converted to the Reactive `Publisher` which is used for the `session.send()`.

I believe there can be used many other approaches, e.g. using a `FluxMessageChannel` bean and its `subscribeTo()` from this `handle(WebSocketSession)` impl to bridge the `Flux` into predefined Integration flow. Or simple `@MessagingGateway` call from the `doOnNext()`.

Not sure, though, if `session.send()` can be used downstream independently (need to play), but you can see in the sample how I propagate a `WebSocketSession` into the `MessageHeaders` to give it access in the Integration flow.

Comment: I seem to have a talent for imagining features Spring team hasn't called yet. If i understood your example, it expects a message on the output channel (at the end of the int-flow) for a single client/session. I have a similar example where I propagate WebSocketMessage, together with its WebSocketSession, but the issue is on how to use thr handler to send a response messave via its session.

Comment: Right, what you see there is indeed *per session*. That's the point of that dynamically registered `IntegrationFlow`. Pay attention how it is removed in the end of session stream life.

Comment: Yup, I have a flow which makes no assumptions on how many clients there might be. If I were to use non-reactive WebSockets, Spring would simply use session id to find a session from session container and  send a message. If you have a suggestion off the top of your head which other avenue I might explore, I'm all ears :D

Comment: Maybe there is just enough to have that `send().subscribe()` ?

Comment: I already thought of that, and I have it in my final flow stage. However, I probably messed something up within my handler, where I subscribe my input channel to session.receive publisher. I have to return some Mono<Void> there, so I tried with Mono.empty(), but I will try your suggestion tomorrow, since I don't have access to code right now, in the middle of the night :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179960/discussion-between-lopina-and-artem-bilan).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your insights, Artem, they helped a lot.

Here's what I ended up doing:

From handler, I simply send received messages to my channel accepting them:

```
public class FakeWebSocketHandler implements WebSocketHandler {
    @Override
    public Mono<Void> handle(WebSocketSession session) {
        session.receive()
            .map(wsm -> MessageBuilder.withPayload(wsm).build())
            .subscribe(subscriberChannel::send);

        return Mono.never();
    }
}
```

And downstream, at the end of my flow, in my final service activator, I send the response:

```
public class FakeResponder extends AbstractMessageHandler {
    @Override
    protected void handleMessageInternal(Message<?> message) {
        final WebSocketSession session = ...; // obtain WebSocketSession for this message

        session.send(Mono.just(message.getPayload())
            .map(this::convertToSomeByteRepresentation)
            .map(bb -> session.binaryMessage(dbf -> dbf.wrap(bb)))
        ).subscribe();
    }
}
```